# Roots of a polynomial equation are homogeneous?

Tags: polynomials

I read that the discriminant of a polynomial $p(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$ is a homogeneous polynomial in the coefficients of $p$. Is it also true that the zeros of polynomial are homogeneous functions of its coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by homogeneous functions of its coefficients?  A homogeneous function is one where $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^kf(x)$.  If you multiply all the coefficients of a polynomial by $\lambda$, you do not change the roots (just factor out $\lambda$).

Comment: So, they are trivially homogeneous of degree 0.

Comment: @Vivek Sure, you could look at that way.  It's more interesting if you multiply the coefficient $a_i$ by $\lambda^{n-i}$.  This scales all your roots by $\lambda$.